# Kivy: Popup can have only one widget as content (When I import two different popup modules)

Tags: python, python-3.x, popup, kivy, kivy-language

I am designing an app using kivy where I need two different Popup Widgets. I designed them using 'kv' language. When I import these Popup modules in my project file, It throws:

> 'Popup can have only one widget as content'

Here is my project file.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from myPopups.Popup1 import Popup1Window
from myPopups.Popup2  import Popup2Window

Builder.load_file('project.kv')
class ProjectWindow(BoxLayout):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.mypopup1 = Popup1Window()
        self.mypopup2 = Popup2Window()
```

Popup1.kv file

```
<Popup>:
    size_hint: 0.4,0.5
    auto_dismiss:True
    title: 'Popup 1'
    id:mypopup1
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        id: header1
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint_y:1
        size_hint_x:1
        padding:3
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:(.06,.35,.45,1)
        BoxLayout:
            id:text_box1
            size_hint_y:None
            size_hint_x:1
            height:60
            TextInput:
                id:txt_qty1
                text:''
                multiline:False
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                font_size:30

        GridLayout:
            id:popup_numpad1
            size_hint_y:None
            size_hint_x:1
            # spacing:'3'
            height:230
            rows:4
            cols:3
            spacing:4

            Button:
                text: 'Popup 1 Button'
                bold:True
                font_size:17
                background_normal:''
                background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
```

Popup1.py file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


Builder.load_file('myPopus/popup1.kv')
class Popup1Window(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print("This is Popup 1")
```

Similarly, Popup2.kv file

```
<Popup>:
    size_hint: 0.4,0.5
    auto_dismiss:True
    title: 'Popup 2'
    id:mypopup2
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        id: header2
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint_y:1
        size_hint_x:1
        padding:3
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:(.06,.35,.45,1)
        BoxLayout:
            id:text_box2
            size_hint_y:None
            size_hint_x:1
            height:60
            TextInput:
                id:txt_qty2
                text:''
                multiline:False
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                font_size:30

        GridLayout:
            id:popup_numpad2
            size_hint_y:None
            size_hint_x:1
            # spacing:'3'
            height:230
            rows:4
            cols:3
            spacing:4

            Button:
                text: 'Popup 2 Button'
                bold:True
                font_size:17
                background_normal:''
                background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
```

Popup2.py file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


Builder.load_file('myPopus/popup2.kv')
class Popup2Window(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print("This is Popup 2")
```

Please help me in this regard. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `kv` files each contain a rule for `<Popup>`. When the second `kv` file is loaded, the contents of the second `<Popup>` rule are added to the first, resulting in a final rule for `<Popup>` that has two children for the `Popup`. When you load a rule for a class (like `<Popup>`) it applies to all instances of `Popup` that are created in your `App` after loading the `kv`. Generally if you want different rules to apply to different instances of `Popup`, you would use subclasses of `Popup` (as you have), and load different rules for each subclass.

You probably want to change the rule in `Popup1.kv` to `<Popup1Window>` and similarly, in `Popup2.kv` change the rule to `<Popup2Window>`.